# Issue when doing fullsceen on 125% scaling

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, intel-graphics, fullscreen

I am using a Lenovo s540 with Ubuntu 20.04 and I have disabled my NVIDIA GeForce MX250 GPU so that I can get a good fractional scale of 125 %.

This is because with my GPU enabled, 125 % scaling gets just too big. It is fine with it disabled, but when I make a YouTube video full screen with disabled GPU on 125 % scaling, it becomes something as this image shows:

[image: YouTube full screen screenshot with 125 % scaling]

Here is a screenshot with 100 % scaling:

[image: YouTube full screen screenshot with 100 % scaling]

My laptop is a 14 inch laptop and with the scaling set to 100 % I almost can't see stuff. I even tried tweaking the text scaling, but that way I have to tweak it for every application separately. Also Firefox doesn't adapt to it if you keep scaling to 100 % and text scaling to maybe 1.05.

I know that I can also change the font, but what I was looking for was a proper fix for this.

Comment: i have Lenovo Yoga C740 with integrated graphic card and scaling does not work properly when set to 125% it causes tearing. Maybe you can set the scaling to 100% and in Tweaks (sudo apt install gnome-tweaks) -> Fonts -> Scaling factor -> Set that to 1.05 or more.. This is the only solution I've got for the moment, which is not the best but is better than having a screen which causes tearing..

Comment: Yes i do agree but my laptop is a 14 inch laptop and with the scaling set to 100% i almost can't see stuff and about the text scaling in tweaks i even tried that but for every app you have to tweak it and also Firefox doesn't adapts to it if you keep scaling to 100% and text scaling to maybe 1.05

Comment: Yea I know mine is also 14 inch..That's true it does not adapt to everything, but you can also change the font on firefox, which I also did and is better..

Comment: Yes all that can be done and is true but what i was looking for was a proper fix for this.

Comment: We can suggest things that work for us. Only you can decide what is a proper fix for you, but if there is no proper fix, please consider other possible solutions. (I am using the full resolution of the screen (no general scaling), and I have tweaked important application programs, for example Firefox and terminal windows, to show text with suitable size).

Comment: So for almost 6-8 months i have been using a single monitor with scaling set to 100% and things as they should show properly and i think i would be using my laptop with a monitor as the only screen and turning of the one on laptop to have a better experience overall, it's not a solution per say but i wanted to work peacefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, and after searching everywhere, I found a way to solve this problem.

All I did was to set scaling to 100% and after that change some settings:

1. Go to **Settings** > **Displays** > Set scaling to 100% and you'd better disable **Fractional Scaling**.
2. Go to **Settings** > **Universal Access** & change the following options:

   - Large Text : Enabled
   - Cursor size : Medium

These settings mostly had the same effect as 125% Scaling for me.

Comment: I spent hours trying to find a solution this issue on a Dell G15 laptop (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti), and nothing worked except for his - thank you for sharing!